# Alternate for $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] while running PHP script from terminal

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal

Am using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in a php script which forms a url.

```
$serverMode = isset ( $_SERVER ['HTTPS'] ) ? "https" : "http";
$serverpath = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : '';
$serverHost = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] :'';
```

my formed path will be like,

```
$path = $serverMode.'://'.$serverHost.$serverpath."images/someinage.png";
```

When i run from a browser the path is formed correctly, but when i sun from terminal

```
php scriptname.php
```

These $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI' ] are ignored. Is there a way to get the path correctly when running from terminal.

Comment: since one server could host thosands of domains how would the command line know which one you where interested in?

Comment: When i run a php script, does it not know, where the script belongs ?

Comment: well that would be run *on* a particular domain

Comment: Yea i need that domain's HOST and URI

Comment: there is no host on the command line. command line php needs no webserver

Comment: My actual work around is not about hosts, but i need to find the path. Which formed correctly when running in browser. I need the link to form correctly when run script is from terminal too.

Am asking for any way to get the path from terminal ?

Comment: . ......................     `__DIR__`

Comment: Yea but when is use `dirname(__FILE__)` it gives the whole path from root `/home/user/var/www/html/projectname/directories/image/image.png` .

When using `REQUEST_URI` it gives from  `projectname/directories/image/image.png`

Is some workaround to get the path as it is REQUESt_URI while using `__FILE__`

Comment: arg we have been over that.